# ¿Cómo agregar un punto al final de la cadena?

Tags: python, string, lista, function, substring

Cómo puedo agregar un punto al final de la cadena que me da como resultado?

```
food_list = ['Bananas', 'Chocolate', 'bread', 'diapers', 'Ice Cream', 'Brownie Mix', 'broccoli']
letter= "b"
    # Your code here:
Grocery_list = [i for i in food_list if i.lower().startswith(letter)]
[x.lower() for x in Grocery_list]

['bananas', 'bread', 'brownie mix', 'broccoli']
```

Answer (score 3):

Pues tu mismo lo has dicho: añadiendo un punto al final de cada elemento ... que viene a ser *sumarle `'.'` a `i`*:

```
food_list = ['Bananas', 'Chocolate', 'bread', 'diapers', 'Ice Cream', 'Brownie Mix', 'broccoli']
letter= "b"

Grocery_list = [i + '.' for i in food_list if i.lower().startswith(letter)]
[x.lower() for x in Grocery_list]

print( Grocery_list )
```

> ['Bananas.', 'bread.', 'Brownie Mix.', 'broccoli.']

Comment: Lo que busco es que la lista Grocery List se imprima con un punto al final del último elemento, lo que quedaría de la siguiente manera: bananas, bread, borwnie mix, brocoli.